# Analyze multiple response field from google doc form

Tags: spss

One of my questionnary made with Google Doc have a multi response set.

Let's say the three possible questions are :

- foo
- bar
- foobar

People where allowed to tick one or more answers.

In my google spreadsheet results, I have :

```
answer1 : foo
answer2 : foo, bar
answer3 : bar, foobar
answer4 : foo, foobar
anwser5 : foobar
etc.
```

How could I analyze this type of result in SPSS ?

I have the intuition that the values could be split in multiple answers to multiple questions by I don't know how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Try to split the answers into three variables - one for each answer.

Comment: It there any automatic way to do this ?

Comment: Yes there is, try transformation -> restructure data (or something like this, I am using a german SPSS version)

Comment: I do not think restructure will help in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try to use the index function when creating a new variable in SPSS.

For example if the answers to be processed are in the ANSWER variable, you can choose Transform / Compute variable..., and make a new numeric variable named FOO, using this function:

`CHAR.INDEX(UPCASE(ANSWER),'FOO') > 0`

This will result a 1 if foo is found in the ANSWER variable, and 0 if not. Then do the same with the other possible answers.

Or you can simply run this syntax:

```
COMPUTE FOO=CHAR.INDEX(UPCASE(ANSWER),'FOO') > 0.
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: Important Note - This works if the response names are not containing each other. The function CHAR.INDEX simply looks for the given string, so if you have "the" and "thesis" in the responses, and search string - for example, "he" - will be found in both of these responses, and the encoding may eventually be wrong. That is why it is worth ensuring that the names of the answers do not contain containing each, or that the searched fragments of the text are as precise as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have SPSS to test it, but this solution could help you http://www.spsstools.net/Syntax/MultipleResp/ParseCommaSeparatedLetters.txt

Answer (score 0):

To split this string into three variables:

Create the three variables, copy the strings, paste in Excel and use the special text option, choose delimiter = comma. This will split the text of the string into three Excel cells. Then you copy and paste into SPSS, all three variables at once.

Dealing with text/data, SPSS splits by variables whenever it meets tabulation (paste into Excel adds the tabulation character where there was a comma). Alternatively plain text editors (free: TextPad, Notepad++) can be used to alter the text.

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "use the special text option".

Comment: Okay I've found it, in Excel 2007: Data > Convert > Use delimiter > Comma
I'll try it to reimport it into SPSS as soon as possible

Comment: Thanks for your answer but all fields are not orgabized well with this method wich makes it not usable