# Separating a string of comma separate values in SPSS

Tags: spss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Analyze multiple response field from google doc form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881079/analyze-multiple-response-field-from-google-doc-form)

The data get's produced by Google Forms.
The user has the ability to check for option in a multi-checkbox:

- "Fishing"
- "Boating"
- "Hiking"
- "Climbing"

If the user checks "Fishing" and "Boating" the result I get is formatted as:
"Fishing,Boating"

How do I reformat that data in a way where I can easily access whether a particular user has check each individual box?

What's the easiest way to do this in SPSS?

This problem came up over at: http://lesswrong.com/r/discussion/lw/f0r/2012_less_wrong_census_survey_call_for/7nob

Comment: This is off-topic on this site, so I have voted to close and migrate to SO. Is this a problem when importing the data, or is the data already in a cell in a data matrix and you just need to parse the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse the data with string-math in SPSS.

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/modules/functions.htm

Section 4 gives some examples.  This would allow you to break them into their own variables and either keep it as String or change it to Binary.